# Is WHERE positioned in a different position in logical query phase compared to physical query process

Tags: sql-server

In terms of the `SQL-server` logical query phases; the `WHERE` clause comes after the `FROM` clause.

I've used the following code:

```
GO
SET showplan_ALL ON;
GO
SELECT  j.Name, 
        q.hoursWorked
FROM    #j j
        INNER JOIN #q q ON
          j.Name = q.Name
WHERE   q.hoursWorked > 9;
GO
SET showplan_ALL OFF;
GO
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Now `WHERE` seems to be part of the nested loop. I thought the nested loop was the join - which is the `FROM` clause.

How does this agree with the logical query phases as `WHERE` seems to be at the same point as `FROM` in the physical plan ?

Comment: That's because your `WHERE` condition is about `JOIN`ed table `q` rows. Filtering the `JOIN`ed table first makes the query faster, because there is less rows to `JOIN`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek does the "Table Scan" gets hold of _all_ the rows where the where predicate applies? or does it just get the _first_ row that it finds and then passes that to the "Clustered Index Seek"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer will push predicates as far down in the query as it reasonably can.

In this case, the `WHERE` clause condition is a condition against a single table - it can avoid retrieving any rows from `q` which will never meet the `WHERE` clause condition, and thus never needs to `JOIN` them at all.

In SQL, you describe *what you want*, not *how to do it*, and the optimizer tries to make smart decisions.

The logical query phases wouldn't be so named if they were also the physical phases. The optimizer has to produce results **as if** the logical order was being followed, but may choose to perform actions in a different order if it is more efficient to do so.

Comment: +1 thanks for info; to use the tool (sql-server) _well_ analysing the plans seems like it might be as important as being able to write the queries?

Comment: @whytheq: *Usually*, it is not required. As Damien wrote: In the SQL statement, you write *what you want*. Then, you rest assured that SQL Server executes the query in the most efficient way possible. Only if SQL Server fails to do that (happens rarely, but happens) or if you want to optimize your indexes you need to look at the execution plan in detail.

Comment: @whytheq - I don't view plans too often these days. They're certainly a useful starting point if a query isn't performing well. Over time, you tend to change the way that you write SQL and (generally) stop writing poorly performing queries in the first place. But, as with many things, it takes practice. It's good that you're learning the tools.

Answer (score 1):

The query optimizer is allowed to choose *any* physical execution plan, as long as the result corresponds to the query. Thus, it may execute conditions, joins and projections in any way it sees fit.

If you need the query parts to be executed in a specific order, you need to use temporary tables and/or [query hints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx). Otherwise, you are not allowed to make *any* assumptions w.r.t. the order of execution.

Comment: +1 thanks for info; analysing these plans is new to me - I'm working through a book by Itzik B-G at the moment but will probably add some further (silly) questions to SO.